# Why when my python code writes files, it seems case-insensitive?

Tags: python, dictionary, case-insensitive

I have a dictionary and want to write the values to files whose names are based on the keys. My keys can be very similar, a letter can be upper or lower case.

```
dict_1 = {'g.XXXXX': '>g|XXXXX|1\nSRGSSAGFDRHITIFSPEGRLYQVEYAFKAINQGGLTSVAVRGKDCA',  'G.XXXXX': '>G|XXXXX|1\nSAGFDRHITIFSPEGRLYQVEYAFKAINQGGLTSVAVRGKDCAVIVTQKKVPDKLLDSSTVTHL'}

for k in dict_1:
    with open(f'{k}.data.txt', 'w') as out:
    out.write(f'{dict_1[k]}\n')
```

The script writes only 'g.XXXXX.data.txt' but with the data of the 'G.XXXXX' key, instead of both files 'g.XXXXX.data.txt' and 'G.XXXXX.data.txt', whith their respective data

Why and how can I fix this? Thanks!

Comment: Are you on Windows? Because file paths are case insensitive.

Comment: Also mac has case insensitive filesystem ..

Comment: I work with a mac (13.2.1). I didn't know about the case insensitive filesystem. Any chance to fix this? The only solution I found is to add an extra character to each key (ex: uG or lg)

Comment: You will indeed have to use different filenames, because a Mac will always choose the same file regardless.

Answer (score 0):

It runs twice, in windows its overwriting the file. it creates two files in Linux.

```
PS C:\work> python a.py
g.XXXXX
G.XXXXX
```